# Java issue with setting value

Tags: java, arraylist, getter-setter

I have the following Java code;

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
response = executeQuery(query);

for(Object[] person : response.getRecords()) {
    Person per = new Person();
    per.setPersonName((String)person[0]);   
    //Setting other values      
    personList.add(per);
}
```

So as you can see, I am getting a response from query execution and get an object array which I am trying to set in my custom class `Person`.

I have the following setter in `Person`;

```
public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
}
```

Now there is something strange happening. I get the response correctly and on debug, if I check/watch for `person[0]`, it is giving me proper value `test1`

But it does not set the same when I am doing `per.setPersonName((String)person[0]);`

It is setting `personName` to `null`

I have verified the type of `personName` which is `String`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show your query.Let us see the query so we can understand projections in your query.

Comment: Is your query returning a list of Object[] ?

Comment: After loop , you see personName to null in person object ?. Code looks like correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting a response from query execution and get an object array
>   which I am trying to set in my custom class Person.

If your loop return `Object[]` than loop should be like

```
for(Object obj : response.getRecords()) {
        Person per = new Person();
        per.setPersonName(/*parse obj to get pserson name*/);   

        personList.add(per);
 }
```

Comment: No bro, It will return Object[] not object.It means List<Object[]> if we have projections in our query

Comment: If, it return 2D Object than will be like: `for(Object[]: ...)`

Comment: But I am unclear what he is asking,which api he is using.Is it hibernate or jdbc

Comment: @ShoaibChikate, I am also unclear, if it return List<Object[]> than his loop is ok.

Comment: @testndtv Does the method getRecords return a single Object array or a collection of Object arrays?

Comment: getRecords returns a collection of Object arrays

Comment: In fact when I check/watch over the for loop statement that I have to iterate, for "Object[] person", I can see all the values

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the code for the response.getRecords() method, I can't be sure, but this could be the problem:

If you use JDBC to retrieve the records, you need to call `ResultSet.next()` before you access the rows because a ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.